# Quill editor inside Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, quill, ngx-quill

In this example, editor is created inside Shadow Root.

https://codepen.io/artemiusgreat/pen/XWMPdWG

The main concern so far is that **inline formatting doesn't work** when initiated from Toolbar module by clicking `Bold` or `Italic` buttons on the panel.

The reason is that `window.getSelection` always returns empty selection inside the Shadow Root.

The good thing is that it somehow works when inline formatting is initiated from Keyboard module by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

I'm digging into the code, but if somebody already resolved this I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

[This fix](https://codepen.io/artemiusgreat/pen/XWMPdWG) doesn't cover missing `shadow.getSelection` in Safari but all other browsers should work. In my case, I needed only Chrome.

```
var quill = new Quill(editorControl, {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow' 
});

const normalizeNative = (nativeRange) => {

  // document.getSelection model has properties startContainer and endContainer
  // shadow.getSelection model has baseNode and focusNode
  // Unify formats to always look like document.getSelection 

  if (nativeRange) {

    const range = nativeRange;
    
    if (range.baseNode) {  
      range.startContainer = nativeRange.baseNode;
      range.endContainer = nativeRange.focusNode;
      range.startOffset = nativeRange.baseOffset;
      range.endOffset = nativeRange.focusOffset;

      if (range.endOffset < range.startOffset) {
        range.startContainer = nativeRange.focusNode;
        range.endContainer = nativeRange.baseNode;    
        range.startOffset = nativeRange.focusOffset;
        range.endOffset = nativeRange.baseOffset;
      }
    }

    if (range.startContainer) {
      
      return {
        start: { node: range.startContainer, offset: range.startOffset },
        end: { node: range.endContainer, offset: range.endOffset },
        native: range
      };
    }
  }

  return null
};

// Hack Quill and replace document.getSelection with shadow.getSelection 

quill.selection.getNativeRange = () => {
  
  const dom = quill.root.getRootNode();
  const selection = dom.getSelection();
  const range = normalizeNative(selection);
  
  return range;
};

// Subscribe to selection change separately, 
// because emitter in Quill doesn't catch this event in Shadow DOM

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", (...args) => {

  // Update selection and some other properties

  quill.selection.update()
});
```

Comment: Really it was a very different scenario, after debugging a lot I observed, shadow root was the main cause. I was working with Angular. So I utilized event "onEditorCreated". In side it I just copy paste your code. It worked then.
I think, if they take "parent context" as an input attribute, then It will not be required in coming future. #ngx-quill.

Comment: Took me 4 days and i finally found this! Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Full HTML file

```html
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>CKEditor</title>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="container" name="NewEditor"></div>

        <script>
                let container = document.querySelector(".container");
                let shadow = container.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
                const ele = document.createElement('div');
                console.log(shadow.getRootNode())
                shadow.innerHTML = `<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css">
                `;
                shadow.appendChild(ele);
                var quill = new Quill(ele, {
                  "modules": {
                    "toolbar": [
                        [
                            "bold",
                            "italic",
                            "underline",
                            "strike",
                            "blockquote",
                            "code-block",
                            {
                                "list": "ordered"
                            },
                            {
                                "list": "bullet"
                            },
                            {
                                "script": "sub"
                            },
                            {
                                "script": "super"
                            },
                            {
                                "indent": -1
                            },
                            {
                                "indent": "+1"
                            },
                            {
                                "direction": "rtl"
                            },
                            {
                                "size": [
                                    "small",
                                    false,
                                    "large",
                                    "huge"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "color": []
                            },
                            {
                                "background": []
                            },
                            {
                                "font": []
                            },
                            {
                                "align": []
                            },
                            "clean",
                            "link",
                            "image",
                            "video"
                        ]
                    ]
                  },
                  "placeholder": "",
                    "readOnly": false,
                    "theme": "snow",
                    "value": {
                        "ops": [
                            {
                                "attributes": {
                                    "bold": true
                                },
                                "insert": "Bold"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
                const normalizeNative = (nativeRange) => {
                  if (nativeRange) {
                    const range = nativeRange;
                    if (range.baseNode) {  
                      range.startContainer = nativeRange.baseNode;
                      range.endContainer = nativeRange.focusNode;
                      range.startOffset = nativeRange.baseOffset;
                      range.endOffset = nativeRange.focusOffset;
                      if (range.endOffset < range.startOffset) {
                        range.startContainer = nativeRange.focusNode;
                        range.endContainer = nativeRange.baseNode;    
                        range.startOffset = nativeRange.focusOffset;
                        range.endOffset = nativeRange.baseOffset;
                      }
                    }
                    if (range.startContainer) {
                      return {
                        start: { node: range.startContainer, offset: range.startOffset },
                        end: { node: range.endContainer, offset: range.endOffset },
                        native: range
                      };
                    }
                  }
                  return null
                };
                quill.selection.getNativeRange = () => {
                  const dom = quill.root.getRootNode();
                  const selection = dom.getSelection();
                  const range =  normalizeNative(selection);
                  // if(selection.focusOffset !== selection.baseOffset){
                  //       range.length = 0;
                  //       document.activeElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('.ql-editor').focus();
                  // }
                  return range;
                };
                document.addEventListener("selectionchange", (...args) => {
                  quill.selection.update()
                });
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

But still 'bubble' theme not working properly.
Getting document.activeElement problem

[Error Line in this iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGSlx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a nice approach in my WebComponent - use a `iframe` tag in your ShadowDOM, and load another HTML page with Quill.